# Simple Unity3d app get stucked on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a rather simple game in Unity3d. The game has about 300 3D objects - all of them have physics, some use cloth.

I am able to open the game on my Android phone, but the app get sucked after 2-3 minutes. The game works fine on my PC.

What am I doing wrong and what can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: are there any error message in adb logcat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use shared material technique, static or dynamic batching, GC.Collect() method and other techniques to improve the performance (you may find them by googling or here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/performance-optimization). Anyway, I would suggest taking a look at Unity's profiler (biult-in) to find the bottlenecks of the app.